# Merge DataFrames based on conditioning datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, filter, merge, date-arithmetic

I am trying to merge 2 Dfs under curtain conditioning on dates.

df 1:
[image]

df2:
[image]

Let's say to today is 2015-01-12, what I'm trying to do is for every clienthostid that has first_activity date earlier than 10 days before today to be excluded from df2, so in the example here I'd be left if df2 with:
[image]

I tried to do so by first merging the 2 df:

```
temp = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='clienthostid', how='inner')
```

and then try to delete according to the condition:

```
temp = temp[temp.First_activity + 10 < today]
```

and I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: cannot operate on a series without a rhs of a series/ndarray of type datetime64[ns] or a timedelta

First_activity and today are datetime64...

I'm not familiar much with sql, python nor pandas (with sums it all I guess :)),
but I've got an assignment to implement this so sorry if the question stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) int value or use [offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
today = pd.datetime.today().date() 
temp = temp[temp.First_activity < today - pd.to_timedelta(10, unit='d')]
```

Or:

```
temp = temp[temp.First_activity < today - pd.offsets.Day(10)]
```